# Inner join few columns of 2 sheets data and paste into another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I've two excel files. In first file there is a sheet respource_master and in second file monthlydata. In Monthlydata.xls file sheet with data with sheet name mdata. The content of this mdata sheet is monthly time entries and rates of each resources. So against each resources there should 20+ rows in that sheet. In resource master sheet in first file, the sheet contains a master table of all resources, means only one row against each resource with emp_code and project name.

So what my requirement is to combine the data from the MonthlyData sheet joined with Resource master and show this combined data in a new sheet say Invoice 3

My knowledge in VBA is very less. So with experience in SQL, my question is it possible to implement it using some JOIN as follows

```
select R.emp_name, R.emp_code,M.hours,M.rate,R.project from
MonthlyData M inner join ResourceMaster R on R.emp_name=M.emp_name
```

If this is not possible how can I accomplish this combined copying between two sheets.

Comment: It is possible. Have a look at ADO.

Comment: If you have Excel 2016 or Office 365 with Power Query then you can also click the solution together in a few simple steps: https://www.powerquery.training/portfolio/merge-tables/